# Retaining and "autoreleasing" in Core Foundation

Tags: objective-c, c, core-foundation

Let's say I'm writing my own function that takes in a CFDataRef object, does something to it, and returns another CFDataRef object:

```
CFDataRef transformData(CFDataRef inData)
{
  //Question 1: Should I call CFRetain(data) here to make sure it doesn't
  //go away? (This of course would involve releasing data just before returning
  //from this function, or as soon as I no longer need data.)

  CFDataRef outData;

  //Somehow produce the new outData from inData (and assume we are the
  //owner of outData, since we created it right here).

  //Question 2: What, if anything, should I do with outData before
  //returning it? I'm unsure of this, because CF doesn't have any
  //autoreleasing mechanism.

  return outData;
}
```

As you can see, I have two questions and they are contained right in the code above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For question 1: The only reason to retain it at the top and release it later would be thread-safety, in the case where you get called from one thread and another thread releases the last ownership of the data, but that won't help: Even if you retain the object, the release might happen before then, or even before you're called, in which case the problem still happens and you've only made it rarer. So I say don't worry about it.

For question 2: Rename your function to `CreateDataByTransformingData`. Then, according to CF memory-management [rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html), your function returns an ownership which the caller must release.

Alternate solution to question 2: Cast to `NSData *` and send it an `autorelease` message. (This requires that you use MRC, not ARC, at least for this module/class.)

[Added 2013-11-01] Alternate alternate solution: Require OS X 10.9 or later and use [the new `CFAutorelease` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_9/CoreFoundation.html).

Comment: Thanks, but take a look at the SecTransformExecute function in SecTransform.h (in Security.framework). This function returns an object, and does not have any “Create” or “Copy” in its name. Still, it returns an object, which means that it expects one to CFRelease it, right? What’s going on there?

Comment: @pf85: According to the CF Memory Management rules (http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html) and implicitly supported by the SecTransform header examples, no, you don't need to release it. (It would probably be worth verifying this in Instruments.) As for how it gets released, one possibility that the transform releases it when it gets deallocated or you execute it again. Another is that it uses the autorelease trick.

Comment: Strangely, the app leaks terribly if I don't CFRelease the returned object from SecTransform. So this is a "bug" in the frameworks or a bad name for the method, right?

Comment: @pf85: There is no method here; that's a function. I don't think there's anything wrong with the function name, but if you need to release the object, then either that's a bug in the framework or the function is mis-named (and in the latter case, the release obligation should be documented, which it currently isn't). I suggest filing a bug: https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: What if it's not a function but an Objective-C method that returns a Core Foundation object? Then the `Create`/`Copy` convention does not apply and the potential leak warning is still there.

Comment: @Rivera There's a different convention for methods: `alloc`, `new`, `retain`, or `copy`.

Comment: @PeterHosey This is not one of those special methods but a simple custom non-CF class' method that returns a Core Foundation object and I would like to make it "autoreleased".

Comment: @Rivera: Then name it without any of those words and do one of the last two solutions in my answer.

Comment: @PeterHosey For your last two solutions: 1) Can't call `autorelease` as I'm using `ARC`; 2) Need to support iOS 5+. I think 1 can be sorted out with ARC-CF ownership bridge, but still feels like a hack and I wonder if there's a "clean" solution.

Comment: @Rivera: Fair enough. IIRC, the solution I used to do involved assigning it to an `__autoreleasing id` variable and then returning the object from that.