# Return Core Foundation object from a non-CF class method using ARC and iOS 5+ support

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, core-foundation

I have this method in a NSObject subclass:

```
- (CFStringRef)UTITypeForPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSString *extension = [path pathExtension];
    CFStringRef result = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)extension, NULL);
    return result;
  }
```

That generates this logic Analyzer warning:

> Potential leak of an object stored into 'result'

The question is how to deal with it in a clean way:

- I can't use [CFAutorelease](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/APIDiffsMacOSX10_9/CoreFoundation.html) because it's iOS 7+ only.
- Can't use Apple Core Foundation naming [conventions](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html) (Create/Get rules) because it is an Objective-C method and not a C function (in contrast with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627848/retaining-and-autoreleasing-in-core-foundation/8628172) related question).

Also I wonder if this method should return a retained object in the first place.

Comment: This is precisely what `CFBridgingRelease()` was built for.  Beyond that you could just bridge the thing and send it an `-autorelease` .

Comment: What does that matter?  Look at the definition of `CFBridgingRelease()`.  ARC or not, the function is available and does precisely what the second half of my comment suggests.

Comment: I was talking about your second option: use `autorelease`. As for the using `CFBridgingRelease`, you mean I should create a "mock" `NSString` reference with it and return the `CFStringRef`? I guess the variable will be autoreleased but there would be a warming about the unused mock variable.

Comment: Why not make it a C function? It is a self-contained set of steps that don’t require access to `self` or other things that can be tricky with C functions, so make it a function and use the CF naming conventions.

Comment: Thanks @ZevEisenberg, that's what I did at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible solutions:

Rename your method according to the naming conventions of the Objective-C [Basic Memory Management Rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH), e.g. start the method name with "copy":

```
- (CFStringRef)copyUTITypeForPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSString *extension = [path pathExtension];
    CFStringRef result = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)extension, NULL);
    return result;
}
```

Then the caller of the method is responsible for releasing the `CFStringRef` eventually.

Or change your method to return `NSString *` instead of `CFStringRef`:

```
- (NSString *)UTITypeForPath:(NSString *)path {
    NSString *extension = [path pathExtension];
    CFStringRef result = UTTypeCreatePreferredIdentifierForTag(kUTTagClassFilenameExtension, (__bridge CFStringRef)extension, NULL);
    return CFBridgingRelease(result);
}
```

In this case ARC will take care of releasing the `NSString` object.

Comment: So in sum there is no *clean* way to keep it: a) a NS method, b) return a `CFStringRef`? As a note: I did finish turning it into a function as your first solution suggests.

Comment: @Rivera: The first solution *is* a NS method returning a CFStringRef (but not autoreleased). - You *could* autorelease a mock NSString object (as discussed in the comments), but then you have to compile this source file without ARC because the ARC compiler does not allow autorelease calls.